# Eonasdan DateTime Picker with mask

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, mask

I am trying to use Eonasdan's bootstrap datetime picker with a mask. That way users can type the date and pick a date very easily.

Is there anyway to do this? I have tried

```
$('#@hp.ID').datetimepicker({
     format: "mm/dd/yyyyy",
     viewMode: "@hp.ViewMode",
     minDate: "1/1/1753"
     }).inputmask("mm/dd/yyyyy")
```

I've also tried digital bush's mask with no success as well. It may be that I am not using or setting it up correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!